# Nested SQL with aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, division

```
SELECT SUM(Item_Qty)/
    (SELECT ABS((SELECT Updated_on 
                 FROM Item_price_hist)-
                (SELECT MIN(Trxn_date) 
                 FROM Transaction)) FROM DUAL) 
FROM  Trxn_Item_xref 
JOIN  Transaction ON Transaction.Trxn_id = Trxn_Item_xref.Trxn_id
WHERE Item_id = (SELECT Item_id FROM Item_price_hist)  
AND   Trxn_date < (SELECT Updated_on FROM Item_price_hist);
```

I keep getting this error:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 988 Column: 30

But I cannot figure  out how differently I should have coded this.

Comment: It really helps when you include table structures, example data and desired/expected results - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is -- no doubt -- a simpler way to write this query.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions should be used by GROUP BY clause.

Can you please specify which tables are you using and what output do you expect out of the query?